How to calculate Count of Columns that greater than zero
I need a T-SQL query that calculates columns greater than zero value.
Sample image is posted below.

I haved tried below query but total count showing wrong.
select 
   Site, cu_id, 
   count(distinct case when divi='EX_TO1' then inv_no end)EX_TO1, 
   count(distinct case when divi='EX_TO2' then inv_no end)EX_TO2, 
   count(distinct case when divi='EX_TO3' then inv_no end)EX_TO3, 
   count(distinct case when divi in ('EX_TO4','EX_TO9') then inv_no end)EX_TO4, 
   count(distinct case when divi='EX_TO5' then inv_no end)EX_TO5, 
   count(distinct case when divi='EX_TO6' then inv_no end)EX_TO6, 
   count(distinct case when divi='EX_TO7' then inv_no end)EX_TO7, 
   count(distinct case when divi='EX_TO8' then inv_no end)EX_TO8, 
   count(distinct inv_no)total 
from OSH 
group by Site,cu_id 
order by  Site,cu_id asc`

sample data

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. Also please provide both sample data and expected results.

My expected results are in yellow color showing in the image. I need to count the columns
EXT_T01 to EXT_T08 . The count of columns should be excluded zeros.

"in the image" exactly... Images are not helpful.

I attempted to format your data, but some of your rows have more columns than you have headers, so it's still messy. Please take a moment to fix it.

Isn't this just a simple: CASE WHEN Col1 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Col2 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ... CASE WHEN ColX <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Also we're still lacking sample data.

Again... Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Data needs to go in the question not an offsite resource.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

A minimal reproducible example is not provided.
Please try the following conceptual solution that is using SQL Server's XML and XQuery.
It is generic, i.e. will work for any number of columns matching EXT_T* naming convention.
Notable points:

CROSS APPLY is producing XML for each row.
XQuery .value() method is using XPath expression to calculate how many columns in question having a value greater than zero.

SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    site varchar(10), 
    cu_id INT, 
    EXT_T01 INT, 
    EXT_T02 INT, 
    EXT_T03 INT, 
    EXT_T04 INT
);
INSERT @tbl (site, cu_id, EXT_T01, EXT_T02, EXT_T03, EXT_T04) VALUES
('SI_BMD_TC', 1730418, 0, 2, 0, 1),
('SI_BMD_TC', 1160418, 0, 0, 0, 0),
('SI_BMD_TC', 4777418, 1, 2, 3, 4);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT *
    , x.value('count(/root/*[substring(local-name(),1,5)="EXT_T"][text()[1] gt 0])', 'INT') AS [counter]
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(x);

Output



site
cu_id
EXT_T01
EXT_T02
EXT_T03
EXT_T04
counter




SI_BMD_TC
1730418
0
2
0
1
2


SI_BMD_TC
1160418
0
0
0
0
0


SI_BMD_TC
4777418
1
2
3
4
4




The above Query worked. Thank you

The Sign function returns the sign of a numeric value as -1, 0, or 1.
If all values are non-negative you can use the following code to count the values greater than zero:
select Sign( EX_TO1 ) + Sign( EX_TO2 ) + ... as [Count] from ...

If the sign of the values is unknown then the following code will return the count of values greater than zero:
select ( Sign( EX_TO1 ) + 1 ) / 2 + ( Sign( EX_TO2 ) + 1 ) / 2 + ... as [Count] from ...

